# Trusted Connection issues with sp_execute_external_script and Python in SQL Server 2019

Tags: python, sql-server

I'm attempting to run a Python script in SQL Server 2019, using sp_execute_external_script.  I'd like to do this using a Trusted Connection instead of providing a SQL user ID and password.

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
         @language = N'Python'
        ,@script = N'
        
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(''Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};''
                      ''Server=MyServerName;''
                      ''Database=MyDBName;''
                      ''Trusted_Connection=yes;'')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(''SELECT 1 AS [Col1]'')

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
        
        '
```

However, I'm getting the error...

*pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'MyDomain\MyServerName$'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'MyDomain\MyServerName$'. (18456)")*

...where MyDomain is the name of my organizations domain and MyServerName$ is the name of the SQL Server followed by a dollar sign.

It would appear that sp_execute_external_script is trying to run under some type of internal service account (?  guessing.  not a DBA by any stretch).  What do I need to change/configure so that the script will run under my credentials?

Alternatively, what needs to be set up for this service (?) account to allow it to run the script?  I did try searching for this account name to see if I could tinker with the permissions, but SQL is kicking back the message "An object (User or Built-in security principal) with the following name cannot be found."  So I'm clearly missing something here.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit 10/23: I'm aware that for this simple example I could pass in the SQL query with the @input_data_1 parameter, but I'm planning for scenarios where I need to use multiple SQL queries within my script.  It's my understanding that passing in multiple @input_data_x parameters is not supported.  Therefore, I'm thinking that I'll need to establish a connection to the local db inside the script as well.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a *remote* server? You lose the benefits of external scripts this way. Scripts are executed by the [Launchpad service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/security/sql-server-launchpad-service-account?view=sql-server-ver15) which uses a local, not internal, account. If that was a domain account, the connection would be made using that. Since it's a *local* account though, it will appear to remote servers as the *computer's* account.

Comment: BTW the same thing happens for local user accounts, services, web apps. It's not something specific to SQL Server

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, no, this is the local server.

Comment: You don't need to connect to the server then, you can pass the data directly to the script [as shown in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-external-script-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-generate-an-r-model-based-on-data-from-sql-server) through the `@input_data...` parameters

Comment: Yes, I can get that to work, but I'm planning for the scenario where I'll need more than one input parameter.  Based on my reading so far, it's my understanding that you can only pass in one input_data_1 parameter with this method (e.g., input_data_2 won't be recognized as valid).  Is that incorrect?